# Change Order Grid Overwrite Problem

Tags: module, adminhtml, grid, magento-1, order-grid

I try to change Order Grid, but I don't know where I have a problem ...
There is my files:

`app/code/local/My/Module/etc/config.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>        
    <global>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_grid>My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
</config>
```

Inside `app/code/local/My/Module/Block/Adminhtml/Order/Grid.php` I've just copy the methods from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid` change class name to `My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid` and comment out this:

```
    $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
        'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
        'index' => 'grand_total',
        'type'  => 'currency',
        'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
    ));
```

I expected that G.T. (Purchased) disappear but is not.
So i tried another easier way. I've just copy `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php` to `app\code\local\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php` and repeat action but still nothing. I'm totally Magento Newbie so please to some help.

Answer (score 1):

Yes that's a known issue when overriding grid blocks.

Basically the problem is that your `My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid::_prepareColumns()` method returns `return parent::_prepareColumns();` which means it returns `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid::prepareColumns()`

Thus the changes you are doing in your custom class are overwritten by the original class.

To fix the issue, replace:

```
return parent::_prepareColumns();
```

With:

```
return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareColumns();
```

In your custom block class. It will fix the issue.

### Using observers instead of block rewrite

On a side note, instead of rewrite the entire block class, which can cause issues when upgrading Magento and/or conflicts with other extensions, I can suggest you use event observers to remove your unwanted column:

Under your `config.xml`, add:

```
<adminhtml>
    <events>
        <!-- Called before HTML render -->
        <adminhtml_block_html_before>
            <observers>
                <custom_before_block>
                    <type>model</type>
                    <class>modulename/observer</class>
                    <method>blockBeforeHtml</method>
                </custom_before_block>
            </observers>
        </adminhtml_block_html_before>
    </events>
</adminhtml>
```

Then create your `Model/Observer.php`:

```
<?php 

class Vendor_Modulename_Model_Observer
{
    public function blockBeforeHtml(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid)
        {
            $block->removeColumn('grand_total');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I edited my module and I have a problem like this:
`Mage registry key "_singleton/My_Module/observer" already exists` . Do you have any idea what it's mean ?

Comment: @Adam yeah sorry made a mistake in the XML I pasted, see my edit

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to much for your help, but still nothing. I don't have any errors but the grid was't changed. Could you check my full code ? And I don't get it, Why comment out `grand_total column` on `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\Sales\Order\Grid.php` do not changing anything ? I changed too returns parameter. I know that core editing is a crime but I wants only check it.

I tried to this [Atwix Extended Grid](https://www.atwix.com/magento/column-to-orders-grid/) but when I added some column from `sale_flat_order` table filtering by status then I received this:

> Integrity constraint violation: 1052 Column 'status' in where clause is ambiguous

I'm not sure but I guess that problem is shown because status filter need to know which table must be use. So if I set main_table.status all will works fine but I don't know how to do this.

First of all `config.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>        
    <global>
        <models>
            <my_module>
                <class>My_Module_Model</class>
            </my_module>
        </models>
        <blocks>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <sales_order_grid>My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid</sales_order_grid>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <adminhtml>
        <events>
            <!-- Called before HTML render -->
            <adminhtml_block_html_before>
                <observers>
                    <custom_before_block>
                        <type>model</type>
                        <class>my_module/observer</class>
                        <method>blockBeforeHtml</method>
                    </custom_before_block>
                </observers>
            </adminhtml_block_html_before>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

I added to it model block but I'm not sure it should be there.

There is my `Grid.php`. Thah you can see I uncomment grand_total and planned to add 2 new column.

```
<?php
    class My_Module_Block_Adminhtml_Order_Grid extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid
    {


    public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->setId('sales_order_grid');
            $this->setUseAjax(true);
            $this->setDefaultSort('created_at');
            $this->setDefaultDir('DESC');
            $this->setSaveParametersInSession(true);
        }

    /**
     * Retrieve collection class
     *
     * @return string
     */
    protected function _getCollectionClass()
    {
        return 'sales/order_grid_collection';
    }

    protected function _prepareCollection()
    {
        $collection = Mage::getResourceModel($this->_getCollectionClass());

        //$select->join('sales_flat_order_item', '`sales_flat_order_item`.order_id=`main_table`.entity_id', array('skus' => new Zend_Db_Expr('group_concat(`sales_flat_order_item`.sku, + " (", ROUND(`sales_flat_order_item`.qty_ordered), + ")" SEPARATOR ", ")'),'total_qty'=> new Zend_Db_Expr('SUM(ROUND(`sales_flat_order_item`.qty_ordered))')));

        $this->setCollection($collection);
        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareCollection();
    }

    protected function _prepareColumns()
    {

        $this->addColumn('real_order_id', array(
            'header'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Order #'),
            'width' => '80px',
            'type'  => 'text',
            'index' => 'increment_id',
        ));

        if (!Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
            $this->addColumn('store_id', array(
                'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased From (Store)'),
                'index'     => 'store_id',
                'type'      => 'store',
                'store_view'=> true,
                'display_deleted' => true,
            ));
        }

        $this->addColumn('created_at', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Purchased On'),
            'index' => 'created_at',
            'type' => 'datetime',
            'width' => '100px',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('billing_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Bill to Name'),
            'index' => 'billing_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('shipping_name', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Ship to Name'),
            'index' => 'shipping_name',
        ));

        $this->addColumn('base_grand_total', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Base)'),
            'index' => 'base_grand_total',
            'type'  => 'currency',
            'currency' => 'base_currency_code',
        ));
/*    
            $this->addColumn('grand_total', array(
                'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('G.T. (Purchased)'),
                'index' => 'grand_total',
                'type'  => 'currency',
                'currency' => 'order_currency_code',
            ));
*/    
        $this->addColumn('status', array(
            'header' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Status'),
            'index' => 'status',
            'type'  => 'options',
            'width' => '70px',
            'options' => Mage::getSingleton('sales/order_config')->getStatuses(),
        ));

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            $this->addColumn('action',
                array(
                    'header'    => Mage::helper('sales')->__('Action'),
                    'width'     => '50px',
                    'type'      => 'action',
                    'getter'     => 'getId',
                    'actions'   => array(
                        array(
                            'caption' => Mage::helper('sales')->__('View'),
                            'url'     => array('base'=>'*/sales_order/view'),
                            'field'   => 'order_id',
                            'data-column' => 'action',
                        )
                    ),
                    'filter'    => false,
                    'sortable'  => false,
                    'index'     => 'stores',
                    'is_system' => true,
            ));
        }
        $this->addRssList('rss/order/new', Mage::helper('sales')->__('New Order RSS'));

        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportCsv', Mage::helper('sales')->__('CSV'));
        $this->addExportType('*/*/exportExcel', Mage::helper('sales')->__('Excel XML'));

        return Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid::_prepareColumns();
    }

    protected function _prepareMassaction()
    {
        $this->setMassactionIdField('entity_id');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setFormFieldName('order_ids');
        $this->getMassactionBlock()->setUseSelectAll(false);

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/cancel')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('cancel_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Cancel'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massCancel'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/hold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('hold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Hold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massHold'),
            ));
        }

        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/unhold')) {
            $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('unhold_order', array(
                 'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Unhold'),
                 'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/massUnhold'),
            ));
        }

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfinvoices_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Invoices'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfinvoices'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfshipments_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Packingslips'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfshipments'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfcreditmemos_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Credit Memos'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfcreditmemos'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('pdfdocs_order', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print All'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/pdfdocs'),
        ));

        $this->getMassactionBlock()->addItem('print_shipping_label', array(
             'label'=> Mage::helper('sales')->__('Print Shipping Labels'),
             'url'  => $this->getUrl('*/sales_order_shipment/massPrintShippingLabel'),
        ));

        return $this;
    }

    public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        if (Mage::getSingleton('admin/session')->isAllowed('sales/order/actions/view')) {
            return $this->getUrl('*/sales_order/view', array('order_id' => $row->getId()));
        }
        return false;
    }

    public function getGridUrl()
    {
        return $this->getUrl('*/*/grid', array('_current'=>true));
    }

}
```

Moreover you have suggested me to create model Observer. Could you tell me If I have Observer which look like this Can I add and remove column only using this file and do not need my Grid.php ?

`Observer.php`:

```
<?php 

class My_Module_Model_Observer
{
    public function blockBeforeHtml(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {
        $block = $observer->getBlock();
        if ($block instanceof Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_Grid)
        {
            $block->removeColumn('grand_total');
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help,
Adam